# Difficulty using Django-AllAuth Example application

Tags: python, django, facebook, oauth, django-allauth

I'm working on a website in which I want to use Django-AllAuth to allow users to sign in using Facebook.  However, I'm a bit stumped.  When I run the example code and then go to "sign up" in the example homepage template, I get the error message shown at the bottom here.  What did I do wrong?

I'm wondering if there are more steps I have to take in order to make this work.  I know the admin page gives you the option to register dummy apps - but I'm not sure I understand what this is for.  Do I need to make my own "authentication app" that users use to sign-in?  Or is this used for the integration of outside apps that I may develop for other purposes (and therefore, not required for sign-in)?

Django error below:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/signup/

'uni_form_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library uni_form_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.uni_form_tags,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.uni_form_tags,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.uni_form_tags,allauth.account.templatetags.uni_form_tags,allauth.socialaccount.templatetags.uni_form_tags

    Request Method:     GET
    Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/signup/
    Django Version:     1.5.1
    Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
    Exception Value:    

'uni_form_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library uni_form_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.uni_form_tags,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.uni_form_tags,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.uni_form_tags,allauth.account.templatetags.uni_form_tags,allauth.socialaccount.templatetags.uni_form_tags

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in load, line 1044
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/snares/sampleapp/django-allauth/example',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_allauth-0.12.0_dev-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']

Server time:    Mon, 24 Jun 2013 15:23:10 -0500
```

Answer (score 0):

`uni_form_tags` not found. It means you didn't install [django-uni-form](https://django-uni-form.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or it not included to your template by `{% load uni_form_tags %}`

Comment: Hi Abbasov, Thanks for the quick reply.  I did install django-uni-form.  I also assume that since this is the example Django project that everything would be included and that this would be a tested app, but perhaps I was mistaken.  When I get a chance this evening I will test if the include is there and re-install djang-uni-form, but I'm not super optimistic since I'm under the impression that this should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need uni-form to test the django-allauth.

I just tried the following and its working flawlessly

```
           1.  cd django-allauth-master/example

[optional] 2.  virtualenv --no-site-packages env
[optional] 3.  source env/bin/activate

           4.  pip install -r requirements.txt
           5.  python manage.py syncdb
           6.  python manage.py runserver
```

goto `127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/` in bowser and you should have your page.

After testing -------
For actual social login to work,  you need to create respective apps from their websites (http://developers.facebook.com   ,    https://code.google.com/apis/console/   ,etc). and supply the KEY and SECRET of each app in `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/socialaccount/socialapp/`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with the example (which I just submitted)
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/425.